# How to keep Gestures Recognizers from Intercepting Messages for a Child

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIview that contains a table view.

I want the user to be able to select items in the table view and I want to be able to identify taps in the parent view, outside the table view.

If I add a Tab Gesture Recognizer to the UIView, the user is unable to select items in the table view.

How can accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, You've to add gesture to your view and you can cancel gesture call back method by doing if touch happen on tableview as below.

1) set TAG to your tableview . `self.tableView.tag = TAG`;

2) Now cancel gesture if touch on tableview as below

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
     id touchView= touch.view;
     if ([touchView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]] || [touchView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] )
    {

        if ( ((UIView*)touchView).tag == TAG) 
            return NO;
     }
     return YES;
}
```

Comment: gestureRecognizer.view will return the main view to which gesture is set and not the tableview.

Comment: @PoojaManiklalBohora You're right. I did mistake, now only updated my answer. Take a look at this.

Comment: This is correct but touch.view will return UITableviewcelcontentview and not uitableview.

with this approach we can set some tag say -100 to your main view
and check

if (touchView.tag!=-100)
    {
   return NO;
    }
    return YES;

Comment: Yes you're right. He has to do some workaround for this. We can do your code, if main may some subview, in those case , your code also doesn't work too. Am I right? But Idea is cancel gesture call back by this delegate method if you don't want to this view.

Comment: My suggestion will surely work as normally we don't set negative tags for any view

Comment: Correct man I accept with your point.(If you see, also same as my point). But main view may have some subviews. if you touch on that subview means, you've to pass that touch.(i'm just told about `!=` operator only)

Answer (score 0):

For those how uses `@IBAction` method. In Interface Builder Tap Gesture Recognizer in Attributes inspector just uncheck "Cancels touches in view".